# Whenever I deploy my project to maven central all my annotations disappear

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, annotations, maven-central

Whenever I deploy my project to maven central all my annotations disappear.

And this phrase remains:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//
```

When i use `maven clean install` All my annotations are still there.

but when i use `maven clean deploy` All my annotations disappear.

In my code, everything is written in Java.

Whenever I import code stored in maven central, all comments disappear.

plz help me

Comment: Can you show the link to your central artifacts? Can you show your project pom/git repository ?

Comment: here https://github.com/HshMaker/sooport

Comment: Oh, there is a target file because I made a mistake in the commit. don't watch this

Comment: Can you explain about what kind of annotations you are talking about because the source does not contain annotations... also you have not configured IntellIJ to download source packages..

Comment: These are all java files in src file. All the comments there will disappear and the comment I mentioned earlier will remain at the top.

Comment: Assuming that by "annotations" you mean "comments": When you deploy by default, you are just deploying the .jar containing the compiled code. So when you try to get the code back, the only way they have to rebuild the source is to decompile the .classes you deployed (and the compiled bytecode has lost all the comments). If you want to preserve all this, you should deploy not only the target but also the sources and the javadoc. See how to do [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-sources-javadoc.html)