# When retrieving dependencies, only JAR files are retrieved

Tags: maven, maven-central

I created a project and uploaded it to maven central. And as a test, I downloaded the uploaded project, but only the JAR file was received, and the source file and javadoc file were not received.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId..</groupId>
       <artifactId>artifactId..</artifactId>
       <version>version..</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier> 
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier> 
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Of course, if I write like this, everything will be imported.

But, I want to be able to receive all files if I just write like this.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>groupId..</groupId>
       <artifactId>artifactId..</artifactId>
       <version>version..</version>
</dependency>
```

help me

Comment: Why do you need the javadoc and sources packages?

Comment: I want to make a complete library first, and without those, the annotations I put on disappear. Is there no way..?

Comment: Annotations are not in source/javadoc ... ? If you have annotations they are in your classes file (also depending what kind of annotations you are using)...

Comment: duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77095345/whenever-i-deploy-my-project-to-maven-central-all-my-annotations-disappear (same person?)

Comment: I uploaded JAR, source, and javadoc to maven central. But if I only get JAR, all my comments will disappear. But when I got the source file, the annotations came back. I'm sorry to ask you a similar question, but I really want to solve it.

Comment: Configure your IDE accordingly to download the source/javadoc packages... That can be configured for IntelliJ/Eclipse or others as well... A dependency is only the jar file which does not contains javadoc/sources etc. it contains the compiles class files...